# Searchable plugin with extended domain classes

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, lucene, grails-orm

Here are a few domain classes and their relationships:

```
class Vehicle {
    Integer hireRatePerHour
}

class Bus extends Vehicle {
    Integer numberOfSeats
}

class Truck extends Vehicle {
    Integer maxLoad
}

class Trip {
    String origin
    String destination
    static belongsTo = [vehicle: Vehicle]
}
```

I want to be able to set `searchable` up so that I can search for trips based on the `numberOfSeats` property of the `Bus` class:

```
def results = Trip.search {
    must(term('numberOfSeats', params.numberOfSeats))
}
```

From what I have seen in the documentation and on the net, `Bus` (or `Vehicle`, not sure because `Bus` extends `Vehicle`) should be set up as a `component`. So this is what I have (in terms of `searchable` configuration):

```
class Trip {
    static searchable = {
        vehicle component: true
    }
}

class Bus {
    static searchable = true
}

class Truck {
    static searchable = true
}

class Vehicle {
    static searchable = true
}
```

However, the `results` is always an empty list. I have used Luke (http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to do a search on `numberOfSeats` and all the results are of class `Bus` (and not of `Trip` which I guess is why my `Trip.search { ... }` doesn't work).

So, after a long explanation... does anyone know how to organise by `static searchable = ...` in my domain classes to be able to do `Trip.search { ... }` using `numberOfSeats`?